# Tennis Ball Probability Question

Tags: probability

Q:I decide to buy a bunch of tennis balls. I have 52 tubes of tennis balls with 13 different colors, with 4 tubes for each color. If the first 5 tubes that I chose at random, without replacement, what is the probability that 4 of those tubes were the same color?

My work: There are $\binom{52}{5} = 2,598,960$ ways of choosing $5$ tubes. There are $\binom{4}{4} = 1$ way to select the $4$ of the same color. So there are $\binom{48}{1} = 48$ ways to select the color. Thus there are a total of $48$ ways to select $5$ tubes such that $4$ of them are the same color, and the probability is: $\frac{48}{2,598,960}= \frac{1}{54,145}$. This is correct?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Perhaps this uses the hypergeometric formula?

Answer (score 4):

There is something missing on your answer, so at that point it is not correct. For each color fixed out of 13 there are $\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{1}$ ways of chosing exatly 4 with that color, so the number of favorable cases must be $13*48$.

Comment: Isn't the answer meant to be a fraction, not just a whole number?

Comment: @a23 i am talking about favorable cases only. I will edit